# Empty static method within Enum

Tags: java, android, enums

- I found this code for some core concepts but i need to know the concepts behind this enum class.
- Kindly can anyone tell how enum class and static methods were working and also eny suitable example for this concepts.

**Code:**

```
enum EBtnSts
{
  static
  {
    ePlayBtn = new EBtnSts("ePlayBtn", 1);

    EBtnSts[] arrayOfEBtnSts = new EBtnSts[0];
    arrayOfEBtnSts[0] = ePlayBtn;

  }
}
```

Comment: http://blog.sanaulla.info/2009/12/01/working-with-java-enumerated-types-enums/

Comment: @SSP Don't cite arbitrary third-party sites as references here. They aren't. References should be to the JLS, the JVM Specification, or a recognized tutorial or book only.

Comment: Ok got it thanks for raising this point

Answer (score 5):

That is a crazy use of a `static initializer`, which you should really avoid. For one, that will certainly throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception.

```
EBtnSts[] arrayOfEBtnSts = new EBtnSts[0];  // Creates an array of length 0
arrayOfEBtnSts[0] = ePlayBtn;    // You can't access any index of 0 length array.
```

Secondly, that code is implementing an `enum` as a normal class. Avoid. The variable `ePlayBtn` should be an enum constant. There should be 2 fields in the `enum` containing the value which you are passing in constructor. And don't invoke the constructor like that.

Also, the creation of array is totally non-sense. You can directly get the array of enum constants using `values()` method of your `enum`.

The `enum` is better implemented as:

```
enum EBtnSts {
    E_PLAY_BTN("ePlayBtn", 1);

    private final String value;
    private final int id;

    private EBtnSts(String value, int id) {
        this.value = value;
        this.id = id;
    }

    private final EBtnSts[] VALUES = values();
}
```

You can learn more about [enum types here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: “And don't invoke the constructor like that.”— is there any java compiler which does not refuse this attempt?